# Why output does not show any thing

Tags: javascript, html

The output shows nothing,what is wrong in the code i could not found out

```html
<!DOCTYPE text>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Exceptional Handling </title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       var a = 200;
       var b = 10;

       try {
         if(b == 0) {
           throw("Divide by zero error");
         } else {
           var c= a / b;
           document.write(c);
         }
       } catch(e) {
         alert("Error"+e);
       } finally() {
         document.write("Anything will be executed here");
       }
</script>
```

The output shows nothing,what is wrong in the code i could not found out

Comment: `finally()` should be `finally`. Refer to the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch

Comment: I vote to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that in a try..catch..finally statement the 'finally' does not have arguments. I've also added a space and semicolon to the alert text, and 
 to the finally statement, in order to make the outputs more pleasant.  I hope this helps.

```
<script>
// For clarity, result is 20. Changing "var b" to 0 throws the error alert.
// 'finally' statement is always executed regardless.

var a = 200;
var b = 10;

try{
  if(b == 0){
throw("Divide by zero error");
} else{
  var c = a/b;
  document.write(c);
  }
}

catch(e){
  alert("Error: "+e);
}

finally{
  document.write("<br>Anything will be executed here");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `finally`, not `finally()`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE text>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Exceptional Handling </title>

     <script type="text/javascript">
       var a = 200;
       var b = 10;

       try {
         if(b == 0) {
           throw("Divide by zero error");
         } else {
           var c= a / b;
           document.write(c);
         }
       } catch(e) {
         alert("Error"+e);
       } finally {
         document.write("Anything will be executed here");
       }
     </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: it is a mistake typing. The question would be probably not useful.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at the browser console, you will see that it encouters an error:

> SyntaxError: missing { before finally block

The error message might not point you to the exact error you did, but reading the documentation about [`try...catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) will do so. `finally` does not have arguments, thus remove the `()` after it and your code will work.